# Looping service call in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs and Springs to develop application..
Following extjs MVC pattern.

Suppose I have an list of 10 Object. I want to loop and make service all by sending One object at a time. I want to send second object only when the service call for first object is successful.

How can I loop and make the service call?

Comment: Is it like you want to update your next callback parameter on sucess of previous callback parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i=0;

function callService(obj){
                Ext.Ajax.request( {
                            url : '../services/xyz?data=obj,
                            method : 'POST',
                            timeout: 300000,

                            success : function(resp, opts) {
                            i++;
                            //do u r stuff here and recall service with next object from array
                            if(i<10){
                            callService(objArray[i])
                            }
                            },
                            failure : function(resp, opts) {

                            }
                        });
}
```